# How do I find out the highest worldwide scores in Temple Run 2?

Tags: temple-run-2

I want to find out what is the current best high score in Temple Run 2 worldwide. Unfortunately I can't find a definitive list. The only option I've seen is on twitter

Do temple run creators themselves have any system so that users can post their high score? The only option I see is tweet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only relevant to a specific moment in time.

Comment: @Ullallulloo, I have also asked if there is any place where I can see current highest score. That's more important part of the question.

Comment: @sakibmoon - I've edited your question to reflect that more. I hope that sounds good to you.

Comment: @Robotnik, Thanks a lot. That sounds a lot better and more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Although the world HS will always change, to view the current one, try looking in Game Center for the leaderboard for Worldwide: many games often have a worldwide leaderboard visible there.

Comment: Apple Game Center? I have android smartphone.

Comment: I don't think Android has an equivalent of the Apple Game Center, so I'm not 100% how to find the world record.

Comment: @sakibmoon That is a pertinent detail that should be in the question.

Comment: @CyberSkull I meant worldwide highest score. Apple game center is fine, But everyone can not see that score, which defeats the purpose. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sakibmoon Most games don't have cross-platform leaderboards, the best one can usually get is a ranking of everyone using a particular platform (e.g. GameCenter, Xbox Live, Steam, etc.).